# Index of the lower_bound of a value in sets and maps in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I want to get the index of the lower_bound of a value in a set and if i type

```
cout<<set.lower_bound(number)-set.begin()<<endl;
```

It is showing an  error: no match for ‘operator-’

The same goes for maps as well,

However for arrays and vectors if i use

```
lower_bound(begin,end,val)-begin
```

it is showing the index

Why is that?

Comment: [Read about what operations can be done with the set iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).  Subtracting one `std::set::iterator` from another is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this because the operator `-` is not defined for the iterators of `std::set`s (bidirectional iterators) while it's defined for the arrays iterators (random access iterators).

Instead, you can use  [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), as follows

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> set {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};
    int number = 3;
    std::cout<<std::distance(set.begin(), set.lower_bound(number))<<std::endl;
}
```

And note that your `set`s will be ordered. I don't know what u  expect.

And as john said there might be a design flaw. maybe you choose the wrong container for your purpose.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the reason operator- is not defined for set and map iterators is because subtracting map and set iterators is a linear time operation. So although you can use std::distance the fact that you need to might indicate a design flaw in your code.

Comment: But random access iterators are also bidirectional right. What's the difference?

Comment: random access iterators do everything that bidirectional iterators do _and more_. (operator - being one of the 'more')

Comment: @TiletiSaiTejaReddy yes the RA its are bidirectional its but there is no versa. u need a good data structure book. for now, I'm giving a small example to show the difference. If you have a vector (the contents are contiguous) you can reach the data by vec[pos] or vec[pos + num] but if u have a list you can't do that because the contents are not contiguous (at most). u can go left and right only (bidirectionally). so to go the desired location go left/right `n` times.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `std::endl` should just be `'\n'`. `'\n'` ends a line; you don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks good point. I usually don't use it but I did because It's use by the OP.